# Hide Subprocess searching information in python

Tags: python, subprocess

This is my code, how can I hide the output of searching in subprocess, I want my code to show just the information of my system.

```
import subprocess
 
Id = subprocess.check_output(['systeminfo']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
new = []
 
for item in Id:
    new.append(str(item.split("\r")[:-1]))
for i in new:
    print(i[2:-2])
```

Answer (score 2):

the progress messages aren't part of the output, they're fed to standard error.

So they won't show in your result. But to silence them and avoid them to be printed when executing the script, just redirect standard error to `NUL`

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.check_output(['systeminfo'],stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL).decode('utf-8',errors='ignore')
```

as a side note, `result` contains Windows end of line characters, that can be split upon just with:

```
result.splitlines()
```